# Firebase check if user session

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, dynamic-content

I am trying to see if a user session already exists, and if it doesn't render a different button option

```
render () {
var actionButton = [];
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    actionButton.push(
      <RoundedButton onPress={() => { NavigationActions.SubmitScreen() }} text='Place Order' />
    )
  } else {
    actionButton.push(
      <RoundedButton onPress={() => { NavigationActions.Login({hide: false}) }} text='Login to Place Order' />
    )
  }
})
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.currentBalance}>
      <Text style={styles.currentBalanceTitle}>CURRENT BALANCE</Text>
      <Text style={styles.currentBalanceAmount}>$0.00</Text>
    </View>
    <AlertMessage title='Nothing to See Here, Move Along' show={this._noRowData()} />
    <View style={styles.heaader}>
      <Text style={styles.item}>Item</Text>
      <Text style={styles.price}>Price</Text>
    </View>
    <ListView
      contentContainerStyle={styles.listContent}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
      enableEmptySections
      pageSize={15}
    />
    {actionButton}
  </View>
)
```

I am then `{actionButton}` to render the result, the problem I am having is that isn't returning a result

Comment: Is it not calling callback function? or not rendering?

Comment: id say not rendering ill update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a good idea to put firebase auth listener in render function. because whenever state updated, it will can render again, which again calls firebase auth listener again. Best place(as of me) is `ComponentDidMount` or `constructor` and change state accordingly. Alternatively you can use state management(like `redux`) to check it user is logged in or not.

Try following snippet:

```
class Orders extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let listener = firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: true
                })
                listener();
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: false
                })
                listener();
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.currentBalance}>
                    <Text style={styles.currentBalanceTitle}>CURRENT BALANCE</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.currentBalanceAmount}>$0.00</Text>
                </View>
                <AlertMessage title='Nothing to See Here, Move Along' show={this._noRowData()} />
                <View style={styles.heaader}>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>Item</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.price}>Price</Text>
                </View>
                <ListView
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.listContent}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
                    enableEmptySections
                    pageSize={15}
                />
                {this.state.isLoggedIn
                    ? <RoundedButton onPress={() => { NavigationActions.SubmitScreen() }} text='Place Order' />
                    : <RoundedButton onPress={() => { NavigationActions.Login({ hide: false }) }} text='Login to Place Order' />
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

You should unsubscribe from Firebase auth listener to avoid undesired behaviors.